# jQuery only works when I paste it in the console

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome Extension, and the click() method I'm calling on an  only works after I paste it in the Extension Inspector's Console.

The markup is like so:

```
<ul id="results-list">
  <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
  ... and so on ...
</ul>
```

So, nothing fancy, really. However, those `<li><a>...</a></li>`'s is being populated based on json data returned from a form submit. So, I think it has something to do with the elements not being there onReady(), but I've tried many times to put the anonymous method (below) inside onReady, outside onReady, and inside & outside onSubmit, and still no luck.

My jQuery is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form').submit(function(){
    ... make the JSON request & populate the form ...
  });
  $("#results-list a").click(function(){
    $('body').width(600);
    return false;
  });
});
```

Anyone have any insight to this? I'm thinking it's either the location of my `.click()` method, or a Chrome Extensions gotcha I don't know about.

Thank you!

Comment: For elements that are added after the page initially loads, you have to use `.live()`: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: No problem!  There is also a `.delegate()` function. This allows you to bind to elements added inside of another element (delegate a function from the parent on element added, in other words). I haven't had a need to use it because I don't have a lot of dynamically-added elements.  If you do have a lot of list items, you may want to check it out: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your event into your callback since the part of the DOM you're trying to access isn't available until it comes back from the server:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form').submit(function(){
    // ... make the JSON request & populate the form ...

    $.ajax({
      url: yourUrl,
      data: yourData,
      success: function(data) {
        // Build your list and then:
        $("#results-list a").click(function(){
          $('body').width(600);
          return false;
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey Josh, thank you very much for posting a response. While that may be a way to make it work, I found Jim's solution (in the comments to my question) as a simpler fix. Thank you again.

Comment: No prob. This will be slightly less overhead than using `.live()` but depending on your needs that probably won't be an issue.